# Setup.py: install lxml with Python2.6 on CentOS

Tags: python, lxml, python-2.6, python-import, centos5

I have installed Python 2.6.6 on CentOS 5.4,

```
[@SC-055 lxml-2.3beta1]$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan  4 2011, 09:49:55) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I want to use the lxml module, but build from sources failed:

```
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:157929: error: ‘xsltLibxsltVersion’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:157941: error: ‘__pyx_v_4lxml_5etree_XSLT_DOC_DEFAULT_LOADER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:157941: error: ‘xsltDocDefaultLoader’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:157950: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__xslt_doc_loader’ undeclared (first use in this function)
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: What version of the libxslt headers are installed on the machine?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I had the same issue, I managed to install it after installing the package `libxslt-devel` and `python-devel` which seems to be your problem:

`yum install libxslt-devel python-devel`

`python setup.py install`

```
Installed /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lxml-2.2.8-py2.6-linux-i686.egg
Processing dependencies for lxml==2.2.8
Finished processing dependencies for lxml==2.2.8
```

However since I also installed other packages in the process, you might want to double check `libxml2`, `libxml2-devel` and `libxslt` while you are at it.

Here is some information on how to build lxml: http://lxml.de/build.html

Comment: many thanks here ~  1 $ sudo yum install libxslt-devel 2. $ sudo easy_install lxml
and it works~

Comment: Just for reference - same problem on Ubuntu fixed with -> apt-get install libxslt1-dev

Comment: python-devel on centos (python-dev on ubuntu) is also required.

Comment: # python setup.py install
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @realtebo You have to `cd` into the folder where you have `setup.py` first (where you downloaded/uncompressed the package)

Answer (score 3):

It solved my problem for nokogiri in Centos

```
sudo yum install -y gcc ruby-devel libxml2 libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

these works for me

```
yum -y install python-devel gcc libxml2 libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel
```

especially the `python-devel`

Answer (score 0):

If the below doesn't work

```
sudo yum install libxslt-devel python-devel
```

try this

```
pip install -U pip setuptools
```

and then install by

```
pip install lxml
```