# Python lxml etree on CentOS 6.3

Tags: python, centos, lxml, centos6

I have Centos 6 on my server and I've been trying to install a few packages (modules) for it. I just brought the ones on my windows to the ftp client in `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages`, but when I run my script one of them - lxml gives me an error:

```
File "plugins/util/http.py", line 12, in <module>
    from lxml import etree, html
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name etree
```

The same code worked perfectly on Windows 7 & Linux Ubuntu 10.04.

Does anyone know why it returns this error? I haven't modified anything, just moved the module from windows to my python2.6 directory on my vps.

@root:

```
>>> import lxml;print lxml
<module 'lxml' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lxml/__init__.pyc'>
>>>
```

@ig

> gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/pip-build/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o

unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: what does `import lxml; print lxml` print?

Comment: @root, edited my first post.

Comment: do you get the same error when you you try to import etree from the interpreter? Or if you add the same line you used in the interpeter to the start of your script does it print the same result?

Comment: @root, yes it still gives me the error above.

Answer (score 6):

Or install it from EPEL (the easiest way):

```
# install EPEL if you don't have it yet
sudo rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
# instal python-lxml
sudo yum -y install python-lxml
```

Answer (score 1):

`lxml` is not a pure Python module. It's mostly written in [Cython](http://cython.org/) and hence compiles to native code. The binary files from your Windows machine are incompatible with CentOS (and Linux in general).

Your best bet is to follow the instructions [on installing `lxml`](http://lxml.de/installation.html), i.e., install the `libxslt-devel` and `libxml2-devel` packages and use `pip` to compile `lxml` or compile it manually yourself. If you go for compiling it yourself, [there's a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642942/setup-py-install-lxml-with-python2-6-on-centos#4643058) with some useful info and further info on the `lxml` site.

---

**Installation**

I don't have a CentOS machine to test this on. The easiest method to install would be via ip, which should be available as a package through Yum. If not, you can install it using the following commands (from the documentation for [distribute](http://packages.python.org/distribute/), a pre-requisite for pip):

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
python distribute_setup.py
easy_install pip
```

From there, just run:

```
pip install lxml
```

And it should install fine.

If you want to skip pip (though, ultimately, pip makes managing dependencies a lot easier, so its well worth doing)

1. Locate the appropriate version of lxml on [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/)
2. Download the source from the download URL (should be a `tar.gz` file)
3. Extract the tar archive using `tar -xzf lxml-<version>.tar.gz`
4. `cd` into the extracted directory and run `python setup.py install`

Note that any of the above commands may need to be run as root if your installation is only modifiable by root. Installation commands are `python distribute_setup.py`, `easy_install pip` and `python setup.py install`.

Comment: "Package libxml2-devel-2.7.6-8.el6_3.4.i686 already installed and latest version" + "Package libxslt-devel-1.1.26-2.el6_3.1.i686 already installed and latest version" ok so all I have to do now is to compile it using pip or myself? Could you please tell me how to compile it myself, never had to deal with such stuff as that..

Comment: thanks for the info, I did it with pip since it looks a bit more simple, but I still get some errors. I edited my first post because it makes my comment too long. I guess the installation is almost done, I did everything how it should be.