# gcc Internal error on lxml installation CentOS

Tags: python, gcc, centos, pip, lxml

I am having some trouble installing `lxml` on `CentOS-6`. I have tried the solutions of some similar questions like, [pip install lxml error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5178416/1113211) or [Setup.py: install lxml with Python2.6 on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4643058/1113211) but these did not work. How to install it correctly?
after issuing,

```
pip install lxml
```

The log is like this,

```
Downloading/unpacking lxml
  Running setup.py egg_info for package lxml
    /usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.4.0.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    /usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.4.0.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/pip-build-root/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
    gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)
    Please submit a full bug report.
    See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-07a07D-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
    /usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'

  warnings.warn(msg)

Building lxml version 3.4.0.

Building without Cython.

Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26

Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64

running install

running build

running build_py

copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes

running build_ext

building 'lxml.etree' extension

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/pip-build-root/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w

gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)

Please submit a full bug report.

See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-07a07D-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-root/lxml
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Traceback in `pip.log`:

```
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 139, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 271, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1185, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 592, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 662, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-cAMY23-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-root/lxml
```

I am using `Python 2.6.6` on `CentOS release 6.5`.

Answer (score 0):

During fresh environment setups/package installation the most common issues one may face are as follows:

1. `gcc` is not installed - a `C` compiler is needed for building `Python` packages as the core is `C`.

   `$sudo yum install gcc`
2. '**error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1**' happens when the header files (#include ) is not found i.e. the dependencies are not installed

   Solution: install the system level dependencies (development packages)

   `$sudo yum install libxml2-devel libxml++-devel libxslt-devel`
3. while in your case, '**gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)**' can't be the above possibilities, the dependencies are there, as not some 'not found' error for any missing header files, or any other syntax level error.
   What has happened (probably), the `gcc` compiler crashed. There's a fair amount of possibility it's a memory problem i.e. low memory.

   Though you haven't mentioned whether you have setup a VM or a native installation - usually we allocate limited memory while setting up VM. If you're using VM the possible way out here is to increase the allocated memory for the `CentOS` VM, or free some memory by closing any unnecessary running programs and services.

P.S. I had the same problem while installing `lxml`, and resolved it with more memory.